# no visible data in table view (heidi sql)

Tags: python-2.7

I have used the following code to load csv data into mariadb and when I view the progress through Heidi sql I can see the data has been loaded, but there is no visibility when I click to the current table or when I run a query. However if I load it directly using the CSV import it seems fine.

I have spent a couple of days looking for a response but have not been able to only found 1 non responded post from about 5 years ago.  I have executed this and commit too so database shows the number of records, but I just cant see it or query them.

```
query = """LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/data/CW_Data/GP_Practices.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE gppractices FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""
```

I am completely new to programming.

Comment: Load Data Infile? This doesn't seem to be related to sql-server. Is your tag really correct?